# Difference between "parents" and "both parents"

Tags: grammar

I've been having some trouble understanding the difference between "parents" and "both parents". When referring to your parents, doesn't that automatically mean your mom and dad because parents is plural? Why would you say "both of my parents"... isn't that being redundant? Whereas if you just say parent, that infers you're talking about either or, right? Any clarification would be great!!

Comment: Please provide a sentence to clarify your issue...using "both" in some cases may be for emphasis.

Comment: In 'General MacArthur has met both my parents' the implication is 'on separate occasions'; not so if 'both' is omitted.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think “both” is just emphasis, not distinguishing time.  Language is often redundant.

Comment: @Xanne I also think that "both" implies dealing with the parents individually, rather than as a group. "I asked both my parents for permission" suggests that you asked each of them. "I asked my parents for permission" would be said if you asked one parent and they answered on behalf of the other, or you asked them together.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that a child could be adopted by more than two adults, although it would be very rare and would have to reflect very special circumstances.

So strictly speaking, *both* in the phrase   "both my parents" is not necessarily pleonastic.

Even in the more standard two-parent situation, this might be done for the sake of emphasis or  because of the context, which you have not provided.

For example, Year 6 (Grade 5) kid shows symptoms of Covid-19.  Teacher says she'll call your Mum to collect you.  But she's at a conference 300 kilometres away.  All right, I'll call your Dad.  " No, both my parents are at the same conference."

You don't need to say "both", but most people do.